# asp:TextBox rendering disabled in FireFox 23.0.1

Tags: asp.net, firefox, webforms

I had a working asp:TextBox control in an old webforms app that broke when FireFox upgraded from version 22.0 to 23.0.1 tonight.  The code looks like:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtChainDescription" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Width="350px" runat="server" />
```

That's all.  This renders in Chrome as

```
<div class="cleditorMain" style="width: 500px; height: 150px;">
   <div class="cleditorToolbar" style="height: 27px;">
       <div class="cleditorGroup">
           <div class="cleditorButton" title="Bold"></div>v class="cleditorGroup">
```

... etc., but renders in FireFox as

```
<div class="cleditorMain" style="width: 500px; height: 150px;">
    <div class="cleditorToolbar">
        <div class="cleditorGroup">
            <div class="cleditorButton cleditorDisabled" title="Bold" disabled="disabled" style="background-color: transparent;"></div>
```

... etc.  So the difference is that the editor button is disabled, and the textarea that needs to be edited seems completely disabled as well.  So a couple questions:

1) Why is this happening?
2) What changed in Firefox from version 22.0 to 23.0.1 that would be responsible for this?

Answer (score 0):

Without testing it I can't say for sure but my money would be on browser definition files, eg please see

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

There's probably an issue with the definition files not recognizing v23 in FF.

Comment: That sounds like it could be possible, though I'm surprised FF going from 22 to 23 would have caused this.  I will test it out, though, and update here.

Comment: That wasn't it.  I tried it and it still isn't working. So another interesting thing I discovered about this text box is that it's being turned into a jQuery.Cleditor at document ready, and I can see it becoming disabled as it loads.  I'm going to try to snag the latest version of that control and see if it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: That didn't fix the problem.  The controls of the cleditor only grey out on clicking the textbox, too.  Bizarre.  Anyone else out there using cleditor?